# How to specify in C# generics such T that is constructible from string? (generic type constraint)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints, .net-4.5

I want to specify required default constructrion options for my T:

```
  public interface IParameter<T>  /* where T : T(string) */ { 
     T Value { get; set; }
  }
```

so I would be able to construct it from given string if passible like this:

```
Value  = "bla";
```

or at least like this:

```
Value = new T("bla");
```

So how to specify in C# generics such T that is constructible from string?

Comment: `string` can't be subclassed so what's the point in making it generic in the first place?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: This is not about subclassing, it is about an arbitrary type `T` having a constructor that accepts a `string` argument.

Comment: Any T has ToString (Addresses, Times, Urls etc), many of such types can be constructed from string.

Comment: Ah, so it's about a constructor that takes a string as argument? Because that is entirely different from the first usage being shown.

Comment: This seems like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, C# does not offer arbitrary constructor signature restrictions for generic parameters. Only [a restricted number of constraints are supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), the closest one of which is the [`new` constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx). However, it serves only for enforcing a parameterless constructor.

You can, however, work around this drawback by working with a factory object that takes a `string` and returns a `T`. First, define an interface for such factory objects:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create(string str);
}
```

Subsequently, you can use that factory type in your interface:

```
public interface IParameter<TFactory, T>
    where TFactory : IFactory<T>
{ 
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to be able to instantiate the factories at will, you can require them to have a parameterless constructor:

```
public interface IParameter<TFactory, T>
    where TFactory : new(), IFactory<T>
{ 
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you could use a generic method to instantiate a `T` based on a `string`, e.g. as an extension method for your interface:

```
public static class ParameterUtilities
{
    public static void AssignValue<TFactory, T>(this IParameter<TFactory, T> prm, string str)
        where TFactory : new(), IFactory<T>
    {
        var factory = new TFactory();
        prm.Value = factory.Create(str);
    }
}
```

As an example of how to use this, let's assume the variable `myPrm` is an instance of that implements your `IParameter` interface with appropriate type arguments. You can then invoke something like this:

```
myPrm.AssignValue("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that  constraint is not legal. Only the parameterless constructor constraint is allowed:

```
where T : new()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because in generic type constraints you can't say that the type must have a specific constructor (only that it must have a parameterless constructor) nor say that it must have specific methods/operators.

BUT

```
public interface IFromString<T>
{
    void DeserializeFromString(string str);
}

public class MyType : IFromString<MyType>
{
    public int Value;

    public void DeserializeFromString(string str)
    {
        Value = int.Parse(str);
    }
}

public interface IParameter<T> where T : IFromString<T>, new()
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter<T> : IParameter<T> where T : IFromString<T>, new()
{
    T Value { get; set; }

    public void Load(string str)
    {
        Value = new T();
        Value.DeserializeFromString(str);
    }
}
```

A classical example... an interface that says that a type can be deserialized from (something) (xml very often :-) )

Use:

```
Parameter<MyType> parameter = new Parameter<MyType>();
parameter.Load(someStringLoadedFromSomewhere);
```

Comment: A slightly nicer approach in some ways might be to specify that no type may legitimately implement `IFromString<out T>` unless it or a parent type includes a static factory method `T ConstructFromString(String st)`, and have a static generic class which can use cache delegates to invoke such method for any particular type `U:IFromString<T>`.  The first time it's accessed for any type `U` would require a reflection lookup, but after that a simple delegate dispatch.  That would avoid the need for a `new` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a constructor in an interface. Depending on your requirements you could use an abstract class:

Pseudo code as not at machine with VS:

```
public abstract class BaseParameter<T>
{ 
    public abstract void BaseParameter(string something);

    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is *not* asking about a constructor of the interface, but about requiring a particular constructor from `T`.

Comment: You can't have a method with the name of the class, nor you can tell that you need a constructor to be implemented in that way (I'm not sure `BaseParameter(string something)` is a method or a constructor)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Suggesting that OP might want to look at abstract classes rather than interfaces based on actual requirements. They are useful at different times.

Comment: @xanatos - Constructor. As I say, not at PC with VS so cannot prove 100% but wanted to show abstract classes as lots of people overlook when using interfaces etc.

Comment: @Belogix: The actual requirements outlined in the question are that `T` is restricted to feature a constructor that accepts a `string` argument. How is your answer related to that?

Comment: @Belogix There is no such thing as an abstract constructor.  You have defined an abstract method that has the same name as the class, which is also not allowed.